# jQuery - How do I get my counter to load only when in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am super new to tinkering around with jQuery. I found a solution for a counter that counts up that serves the purpose for showing savings in %.

The problem that I have with it, is that it runs as soon as the page loads, and the element is a bit further down the screen, and it looses the effect because by the time a visitor sees the site, the counter has already reached the number.

I need to wait to load until it comes into view within the browser. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```js
(function ($) {
 $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
  options = options || {};

  return $(this).each(function () {
   // set options for current element
   var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
    from:            $(this).data('from'),
    to:              $(this).data('to'),
    speed:           $(this).data('speed'),
    refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
    decimals:        $(this).data('decimals')
   }, options);

   // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
   var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
    increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

   // references & variables that will change with each update
   var self = this,
    $self = $(this),
    loopCount = 0,
    value = settings.from,
    data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

   $self.data('countTo', data);

   // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
   if (data.interval) {
    clearInterval(data.interval);
   }
   data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

   // initialize the element with the starting value
   render(value);

   function updateTimer() {
    value += increment;
    loopCount++;

    render(value);

    if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
     settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
    }

    if (loopCount >= loops) {
     // remove the interval
     $self.removeData('countTo');
     clearInterval(data.interval);
     value = settings.to;

     if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
      settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
     }
    }
   }

   function render(value) {
    var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
    $self.text(formattedValue);
   }
  });
 };

 $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
  from: 0,               // the number the element should start at
  to: 0,                 // the number the element should end at
  speed: 5000,           // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
  refreshInterval: 1000,  // how often the element should be updated
  decimals: 0,           // the number of decimal places to show
  formatter: formatter,  // handler for formatting the value before rendering
  onUpdate: null,        // callback method for every time the element is updated
  onComplete: null       // callback method for when the element finishes updating
 };

 function formatter(value, settings) {
  return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
 }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<div class="ui-129 text-center">
  <div id="counter" class="counter-item">
    <!-- Icon -->
    <i class="fa fa-usd green">                                              
      <!-- Number -->
    <span class="number-count" data-from="0" data-to="28" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="10"></span>%
    </i>
    <!-- Border -->
    <hr class="br-green" />
    <!-- Heading -->
    <h5>less than the "other guys"</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End CountUP -->

<script> <!-- I have this script in my custom.js folder, not in the html -->
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.number-count').countTo();
   
    });  
</script>
```

All of the CSS renders and runs properly .. if I need to add it here, please let me know, I'll be happy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can manipulate your script using `scroll` event.

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
var message = $('#message');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView('#hiddenElem')) {
    message.text("Visible");
  } else {
    message.text("Invisible");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 style="position:fixed;top: 0;left: 0;background: white" id="message"></h3>
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<br>Hello..
<div id="hiddenElem">HiddenElem</div>
```

> In your case, try this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if (isScrolledIntoView('#hiddenElem')) {
        $('.number-count').countTo();
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.
I'm not really sure where to put this code, I'm not sure what to change in the code you provided to make it fit my needs. 
I do know that the .text in the variable 'message' needs to be changed as I'm not trying to display text. At that point, I'm not sure what to change or if this will work to start my counter.

Comment: Do you want your cunter to stop if user reached the element at the bottom and scrolls up again ? Or just start the counter once user scrolls down to the element ?

Comment: I just need it to start once the user reaches the element. Once they view the element, it has served it's purpose and can remain static unless the page is refreshed.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing that I change #hidenElem to the id of the element I want to be in view to trigger the start of the counter? 

Do I replace my $(document).ready with this code....

Comment: Ok, so I apologize for being such a pain on this one... I promise next week after this project is done, I am diving into a js and jQuery course. 

I replaced the $(document).load .... with the $(window).on('scroll', ... you posted here. I replaced #hiddenElem with #counter, which is of course the counter element and the element I want to be in view to start the counter... However, this is not working. The counter is not starting

Comment: Debug it whether condition is being satisfied or not. Please provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lamsharkie/spe3ru39/

< The fiddle link. I have the HTML for the element in question, some br to create a scrolling environment, the js file that controls the timer... and in the html the script that you included. I also threw in a bit of css just to show the $ icon and the color (irrelevant) it is supposed to be.

Comment: PERFECT! That works! I was leaving off the function portion that you had typed in the first iteration above. Combining that function and replacing that $(window).scroll with $(window).on('scroll'.... worked perfectly!! Thank you! I would vote your answer up, but I'm not quite there on reputation points just yet.